# UK visa refusal for Syrian because of no proof of ties to Lebanon

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, syrian-citizens, proof-of-ties

I am a Syrian citizen living in Lebanon for the past 25 years. I am here legally, I am 27. I cant work in Lebanon as it's not allowed.

I have applied for a uk short term student visa and it was rejected because:

> a. There is no expectation of a reasonable relationship or strength of ties to country of origin.
>
> b. There is no information to explain the evidence of the origin of the money in my parents bank account.
>
> c. You have provided no evidence of your own circumstances in Lebanon or reasons why you want to study English language.

I have friends in the UK who can help me. For them the main concern is that I will stay there. How am I going to deliver the message that I will leave the UK before my visa expiry date? My travel history is 0. The bank statement was for the past 6 months and it was 20 times more the amount I have to pay for the tuition.

Comment: From what you say about your current position it's going to be very difficult to get a UK visa, near impossible.

Comment: i have the money to pay for the stay and travel and all expenses what is the difficult part to try to fix it ?

Comment: Your ties to Lebanon, you can't work there, UK will assume you're coming to work.

Comment: Sorry, I think your chance of getting a UK visa is nil until your circumstances change. You need to get a job first to have a chance at showing sufficient ties.

Comment: I don't work, I don't need a job.I can pay someone to give me a paper that I work for them, would that be enough ? After all I have way more than enough money to cover all my travel expenses ( my parents money ) I even presented a paper signed by them that and still refused it.

Comment: "I can pay someone to give me a paper that I work for them". That would be called fraud, and would get you banned from the UK for ten years, with virtually no chance of ever being admitted after that.

Comment: i know but what is the legal way to do it, I did provide them with everything I am starting to lose hope. travel freedom is zero

Comment: The legal way is to get a job (as you're not allowed to work in Lebanon, you'll have to move, probably Syria is the easiest) and some ties to a country that the UK will then believe that you want to return to. Building ties to a new country probably takes years, so forget about travelling to the UK for the near future.

Comment: Remember that the UK authorities almost certainly knows that people in your situation are not allowed to work in Lebanon, so paying someone to say that you did work for them, is quite easily revealed fraud.

Answer (score 3):

It’s not what you want to hear but IMHO you have zero chance of getting a UK visa based on your current personal circumstances. You fit the profile of a high risk applicant - young, no ties to your country of residence, existing connections in the UK etc etc. All of that will lead an ECO to conclude that the risk of an illegal overstay is unacceptably high.